# Regexp in php: how do I filter dynamic strings like abc/123/...?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to filter out all characters before the first `/` sign. I have strings like

```
ABC/123/...
```

and I am trying to filter out `ABC`, `123` and `...` into separate strings. I have alsmost succeeded with the parsing of the first letters before the `/` sign except that the `/` sign is part of the match, which I don´t want to.

```
<?php
    $string = "ABC/123/...";
    $pattern = '/.*?\//';
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);  
?>
```

The letters before the first`/` can differ both in length and characters, so a string could also look like `EEEE/1111/aaaa`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to split the string using `/` as the delimiter, you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php).

```
$array = explode("/", $string);
```

And if you are looking only for the first element, you can use [array_shift](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-shift.php).

```
$array = array_shift(explode("/", $string));
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your initial question ? Thank you !